# sbt web plugin: Not a valid key: jetty-run (similar: jetty-port, jetty-context, run)

Tags: scala, sbt, xsbt-web-plugin

I'm trying to set up a scala sbt project with the lift web framework. I'm using

- scala 2.9.0-1
- sbt 0.10.1
- lift 2.3
- xsbt-web-plugin 0.1.1 (which is only on scala 2.8.1, see end of question)

(quite recent versions I know).
I followed http://d.hatena.ne.jp/k4200/20110711/1310354698 and https://github.com/siasia/xsbt-web-plugin/blob/master/README.md to obtain the following sbt configuration files:

project/build.properties

`sbt.version=0.10.1`

project/plugins/build.sbt

```
resolvers += "Web plugin repo" at "http://siasia.github.com/maven2"

libraryDependencies <+= sbtVersion(v => "com.github.siasia" % "xsbt-web-plugin_2.8.1" % ("0.1.1-"+v))
```

project/Build.scala

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object BuildSettings {
  val buildOrganization = "xbaz"
  val buildScalaVersion = "2.9.0-1"
  val buildVersion      = "0.0.1"

  val buildSettings = Defaults.defaultSettings ++ Seq (
    organization := buildOrganization,
    scalaVersion := buildScalaVersion,
    version      := buildVersion)
}

object Resolvers {
  val webPluginRepo = "Web plugin repo" at "http://siasia.github.com/maven2"
  val jettyRepo = "Jetty Repo" at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty"
}

object Dependencies {

 // web plugin
  val webPluginDeps = Seq(
    "org.mortbay.jetty" % "jetty" % "6.1.26" % "jetty", // The last part is "jetty" not "test".
    "javax.servlet" % "servlet-api" % "2.5" % "provided->default"
  )

  val liftDeps = {
    val liftVersion = "2.3" // I'll switch to 2.3 soon!
    Seq(
      "net.liftweb" % "lift-webkit_2.8.1" % liftVersion % "compile->default",
      "net.liftweb" % "lift-mapper_2.8.1" % liftVersion % "compile->default"
    )
  }

  val scalaTest = "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.9.0" % "1.6.1" % "test"
  val apacheHttpClient = "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpclient" % "4.1.1"
  val apacheHttpCore = "org.apache.httpcomponents" % "httpcore" % "4.1.1"

  // Logging
  lazy val grizzled = "org.clapper" % "grizzled-slf4j_2.8.1" % "0.5"
  lazy val junit = "junit" % "junit" % "4.8" % "test"
  lazy val logback_core = "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-core" % "0.9.24" % "compile" //LGPL 2.1
  lazy val logback_classic = "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "0.9.24" % "compile" //LGPL 2.1
  lazy val log4j_over_slf4j = "org.slf4j" % "log4j-over-slf4j" % "1.6.1"


  val logDeps = Seq(grizzled, log4j_over_slf4j, logback_core, logback_classic)
}


object MyBuild extends Build {
  import com.github.siasia.WebPlugin._ // web plugin
  import BuildSettings._
  import Dependencies._
  import Resolvers._

  //End dependencies

  lazy val root = Project("root", file(".") , settings = buildSettings ++
    Seq( name := "foo")
  ) aggregate(core, cli, web)
    //  mainClass:= Some("Main"))

  lazy val core : Project = Project("core", file("core"), delegates = root :: Nil, settings = buildSettings ++
    Seq(
    name := "foo-core",
    libraryDependencies ++= logDeps ++ Seq(scalaTest, apacheHttpClient, apacheHttpCore)
    )
  )

  lazy val cli: Project = Project("cli", file("cli"), settings = buildSettings ++ 
    Seq(
    name := "foo-cli",
    libraryDependencies ++= logDeps ++ Seq(apacheHttpClient),
    fork in run := true,
    javaOptions in run += "-Djava.library.path=/home/jolivier/Projets/asknow/lib/jnotify-lib-0.93"
  )) dependsOn(core) settings(
  )

  lazy val web: Project = Project("web", file("web"), settings = buildSettings ++
    Seq (resolvers := Seq(webPluginRepo, jettyRepo),
    name := "foo-http",
    libraryDependencies ++= logDeps ++ webPluginDeps ++ liftDeps
    ) ++ 
    webSettings
  ) dependsOn(core)
}
```

When I try sbt jetty-run I get the following error message:

```
[error] Not a valid command: jetty-run
[error] Not a valid project ID: jetty-run
[error] Not a valid configuration: jetty-run
[error] Not a valid key: jetty-run (similar: jetty-port, jetty-context, run)
[error] jetty-run
[error]
```

So I noticed that some jetty-* commands do exist, but not the one I want, so I printed webSettings which is supposed to contain all these new settings and it contains jetty-context and jetty-port, as well as jetty-configuration and others, but not jetty-run :s.

What did I go wrong to not have jetty-run?

I tried switching to scala-2.8.1 since the web plugin is currently only on scala 2.8.1, by changing my buildScalaVersion variable but that didn't change anything.  Do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tasks are aggregated; commands are not.

`jetty-run` is a command. It is only available in the context of the sub-project with the web plugin settings.

```
> project web
> jetty-run
```

Once it is running, you can use the `prepare-webapp` task to redeploy the webapp. This can be run from the context of the `root` project, because it aggregates the web project.

Comment: oh ok, I'm fairly new to sbt and didn't get this kind of subtlety, i tried also web/jetty-run since i start the run with cli/run but that didn't work either...
I also had to switch to scala-2.8.1 for binary incompabilities but it looks good now :)
Thanks a lot!